# iPhone application provisioning profile

Tags: iphone

I am working on my iphone application and it was working on the device. I don't know what I did but now it says "App cannot be installed on the device. Please install the provisioning profile abc_pop". When I say install and run then it says failed to run on device. what should i do. How can I reset everything. I know it was working before.

Comment: This might sound odd but restarting xcode actually works for me most of the time

Comment: I restarted a number of times. It says that I am not using the same provisioning profile that was I originally signed. I tried all of them and none of them is working now.

Comment: @Rudiger, You were right! I was not closing the whole app (XCode). Thanks problem solved!

Comment: You must add UDID of your iPhone.
Detailed in :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804332/how-to-add-udid-to-the-provisioning-profile

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you have the correct provisioning profile selected in your project settings. In XCode, go to Project->Edit Active Target, and then scroll down to "Code Signing Identity". Make sure that field has "abc_pop" selected, or, if not, then click on this field and select "abc_pop" from the list. Then try building again and see if it works.

Another possibility is that your provisioning profile may have expired. If this is the case, you'll need to renew it on http://developer.apple.com/iphone

Comment: Try deleting the provisioning profile from your device. This can be done in the Settings app->General->Profiles. Find the profile and delete it. Also delete any other "expired" profiles if there are any -- Apple has some bug where expired profiles can cause totally unrelated problems on the phone. Once you've done this, try building and running on your phone again. It should ask you to reinstall the profile on your device, say Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Just from above, restarting Xcode often works. It's happened to me a number of times, doesn't always work though