# How to add UDID to the provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, certificate, udid

I have 3 iOS devices for which I want to deploy the application. How can I add the UDIDs of my devices to the mobile provisioning profile so that I can deploy ad-hoc IPAs to the devices?

I am unable to add UDIDs to the provisioning profile.

Thanks,
Ankit.

Comment: Last time somebody did that for me, he went ahead to the Apple Developer Center (developer.apple.com), logged in and did stuff there.

Comment: You can find the procedure in Apple Developer website

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you need to find out your UDID then visit here: http://whatsmyudid.com/

If you already know your UDID then go to the Devices section of your [iOS Provisioning Portal](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/devices/index.action) and click "Add Devices":

[image: Provisioning Portal]

Enter in your Device Name and UDID (it's best to copy and paste) and hit Submit:

[image: EnterUDID]

Once successful you can then create a App ID and add the devices to that.

Comment: Hi, I'm having issues trying to register the emulated devices as my device for my profile.. any help.