# Signing IPA file and install it trough Diawi

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, signing, sideloading

As I said in the title, I wanted to know how to sign an IPA file to upload it to Diawi to install it directly from my iPhone. I already tried, but it didn't work, steps I followed:

1. Open Xcode and create a new project.
2. Choose Single-View Application.
3. Choose a name for the profile & app.
4. Choose the provisioning team Apple-ID.
5. Select my connected iDevice from the list.
6. Open iOS App Signer and select the IPA file.
7. Sign it.
8. Upload it to Diawi.
9. Tried to install.
10. Failed.

When it comes to installing the app, I click the install button, it starts installing the app but then it fails and the app icon becomes gray. The message prompt says: "Unable to Download App // "***" could not be downloaded at this time. // Done // Retry."
If I check the UDID is the same of my device.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: did you add your devices UDID to your provision profile you are using for this project ?

Comment: I think not, say me how to do that so that I can tell you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804332/how-to-add-udid-to-the-provisioning-profile ,  check this , hopefully works for you

Answer (score 0):

Add your device UDID in devices section. Then edit your provisioning profile and add your device to it. 
Then create IPA and upload it to diawi